# How to convert policy routing rules using "all" and "iif" to OpenWRT's UCI format?

Tags: openwrt, iproute, openwisp

I would understand if it's possible, and if yes how, to convert the following rules to [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) UCI format using the `rule` directive:

```
ip rule add to all table 111 pref 4
ip rule add from 10.0.0.1/24 lookup 113 pref 32768
ip rule add iif lo lookup 113 pref 32768
ip rule add from all lookup 112 pref 32769
```

I also have a default route to add to a specific table:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev br-lan table 113
```

I guess for this one I will have to use the `route` directive, I'm just not sure how and I will like to familiarise more with the **OpenWRT UCI** way of doing this.

I also want to learn this because I would like to improve the automation facility present in [OpenWISP (an open source wifi controller)](http://openwisp.org/).

Thanks in advance

Federico